# Souble condition in IF statement PHP

Tags: php

Happy easter everyone! :)

Does anyone know what's wrong with this double IF condition:

```
 if (empty($_POST['request_article_form'])) and empty($_POST['article_number_article_table']))    {//blabla }
```

Error from IDE: 
 Fix [1/1] Syntax error, unexpected T_LOGICAL_AND on line 37

Answer (score 2, accepted):

')' is added  extra

Use this

```
if (empty($_POST['request_article_form']) and empty($_POST['article_number_article_table'])) { 
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just count brackets, you open it 3 times, close 4 times.

```
if (empty($_POST['request_article_form']) and empty($_POST['article_number_article_table'])) { 
    // do something
}
```